# how to restrict write to column in mysql to procedures only

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, innodb

Is there a way to restrict insert or update to specific columns in a table using innodb engine in MySQL? I want to update these columns only through triggers or procedures

What I want to do is to calculate these columns automatically and not allow the change of these directly. Let me know if my approach is not correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Let me know if my approach is not correct

Your approach is unusual, but not impossible.  Whether it is "correct" will depend on factors not mentioned in your question:

- If the columns are always the result of some simple expression, you could simply specify that expression in each [`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select.html):

  ```
  SELECT col_a, col_b, LEAST(10*col_a, 5*col_b) AS calculated_column
  FROM   mytbl
  WHERE  ...
  ```

  Or store the results in a [view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/views.html) so that you don't need to write the expression(s) every time:

  ```
  CREATE VIEW myview AS
  SELECT col_a, col_b, LEAST(10*col_a, 5*col_b) AS calculated_column
  FROM   mytbl
  ```

  In which case, to select the results one merely need do:

  ```
  SELECT * FROM myview WHERE ...
  ```

  However, note that `calculated_column` will still be evaluated each time you select from the view, so could lead to performance problems if it's a complicated expression or your table is large.  If instead you want to store the result of the calculation (so that it need not be evaluated on each `SELECT`), you could define [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/triggers.html) that overwrite any value supplied by the user:

  ```
  CREATE TRIGGER mytbl_insert AFTER INSERT ON mytbl FOR EACH ROW SET
    NEW.calculated_column = LEAST(10*NEW.col_a, 5*NEW.col_b);

  CREATE TRIGGER mytbl_update AFTER UPDATE ON mytbl FOR EACH ROW SET
    NEW.calculated_column = LEAST(10*NEW.col_a, 5*NEW.col_b);
  ```
- If the columns will actually be periodically updated, but only from a stored procedure:

  1. Deny your existing user(s) permission to update the columns:

     ```
     REVOKE INSERT (col1, col2), UPDATE (col1, col2) ON mydb.mytbl FROM myuser;
     ```

     Note that if your user has table- or database-level privileges, they will need to be revoked and replaced with column-level ones as appropriate.
  2. Create a user under which the procedure will run:

     ```
     GRANT INSERT, UPDATE ON mydb.mytbl TO
     'procuser'@'nonexistent' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '';
     ```
  3. Define your procedure to run under that new user:

     ```
     CREATE DEFINER = 'procuser'@'nonexistent' PROCEDURE ...
     ```

Comment: @gehad: It would depend on exactly what business problem I was trying to solve... ;)

Comment: I get SQL Error (1147): There is no such grant defined for user 'root' on host 'localhost' on table 'tbl_order'

Comment: nevermind, I was trying to revoke access from root user. I created another user and it worked fine